# Proper way to send UI notifications using NGXS

Tags: javascript, angular, notifications, ngxs

I'm new in NGXS and I try to figure out the right way to send UI toast notifications after success/error HTTP response using NGXS? Should we handle it in state:

```
  @Action(SomeRequestSuccess)
  public success(ctx: StateContext<SomeModel>, action: SomeRequestSuccess) {
    // like this
    this.store.dispatch([new SuccessToastNotification(msg)])
    // or just use service
    this.toastsService.showToast(action.payload.message, ToastsTypes.SUCCESS);
  }
```

or somehow keep error/success response in state and then use it in component:

```
@Select(selectors.someRequestSuccess) public success$: Observable<any>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.success$.subscribe(s => 
      this.toastsService.showToast(s.message, ToastsTypes.SUCCESS);
      this.reloadReport();
  );
}

// and same way for error
...
```

or any other way that you could suggest. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example, using a service, is my favorite approach for this kind of feature. Just remember that if this service returns a `Subscribable` or a `Promise` you can return the call to the `showToast` method to have the action lifecycle connected with the async operation.

Another approach is dispatching an action, also in your first example, and then grabbing this action using the `ActionStream` like shown below:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { State, Actions, ofActionDispatched } from '@ngxs/store';

@State({...})
@Injectable()
export class MyState implements NgxsAfterBootstrap {
  constructor(action$: Actions) {}

  ngxsAfterBootstrap() {
    // synchronos
    action$.pipe(
      ofAction(SuccessToastNotification),
      tap(msg => this.toastsService.showToast(msg, ToastsTypes.SUCCESS))
    )

    // asynchronos
    action$.pipe(
      ofAction(SuccessToastNotification),
      mergeMap(msg => this.toastsService.showToast(msg, ToastsTypes.SUCCESS))
    )
  }
}
```

If you want more info about action handlers you can find in [NGXS docs](https://www.ngxs.io/advanced/action-handlers). The choice between these two approaches will depend on your team preferences and guidelines.